# How to use swift class in Objective C on Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit

I wanted to learn how objective c works so i create a new view controller with objective c within my swiftapp. I have managed to connect objective-c to swift but not swift to Objective C.

I tried googling it, and my project does not have module name, i think it's probably because it's a swift project.

so i use product name because i didnt do anything on the project settings except for lowering the ios version

and this is what i got

[image]

so how does one add swift class to objective c in swift project? Thanks

Comment: Why did you add a subdirectory ?

Comment: random, does it affect in anyway?

Comment: the root dir is rawg.IOS

Comment: i read the apple docs, and it show it like that or just Rawg.IOS-Swift.h , both does not work

Comment: Can you show the Objective-C interface and the swift interface ?

Comment: If you want to learn Objective-C it would have been easier to start by building a Objective-C program first before going to the mixing part.

Comment: that's the problem, i do not have the swift interface

Comment: its PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME. it exists everywhere

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
#import "yourTargetName-Swift.h"
```